# How do I print only the letter before a slash "/" in my program?

Tags: java, string

I have a date 07/December/2020, and I want to print JUST the last letter of December, R, before the slash. I am going to then combine this last letter with the first letter of December by concatenating them so it says 'DR'. This is a lot easier in theory...

```
 class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    String dateCod = "07/December/2020";
    String firstletterLastletter= (dateCod.substring(3,4) + dateCod.substring(9));
  }
}
    System.out.println(firstletterLastletter);
  }
}
```

I tried this, but it won't work. I also tried paring it with substring and lastIndexOf combined, but that wouldn't work. I feel like I have no idea what I am doing, and feebly trying to understand how to do something by throwing darts in the dark...

**How can I print just the last letter before the second slash?**

Comment: **"but that wouldn't work"** - so what exactly was the result you got, and in what way was it unexpected? You need to provide us with that sort of information in order to help us to see what is going wrong. In this case, we can see what is going wrong (single-argument substring method returns the entire rest of the string after the index, not just one char), but it's a lot easier if we always provide all of the information we have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `split()` to get the middle part of the String and then use `charAt()` method to get character at specific index.

```
 String dateCod = "07/December/2020";
 String middle = dateCod.split("/")[1];
 String res = middle.charAt(0) + "" + middle.charAt(middle.length() - 1);
```

If you want to later print it as `DR` use `toUppercase()` method on `res`

Comment: Nice answer. I'd suggest avoiding the JS-style type coercion effect you get by adding a blank `String` to a `char`, because in Java, this is a bit of a hack. It might be nicer to do something like `String.valueOf(a) + b` rather than `a + "" + b`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceAll` with regex

```
 String result = dateCod.replaceAll(".*/(.)[^/]+(.)/[^/]*", "$1$2");// Output Dr
```

---

#### regex demo

Answer (score 0):

You can still get what you want with [substring()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-), but the key is splitting the date string into tokens first. Splitting allows you to avoid dealing with the different quantity of characters in each month name.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "07/December/2020";

        String[] tokens = s.split("/");

        String month = tokens[1];

        String firstLetter = month.substring(0, 1);
        String lastLetter = month.substring(month.length() - 1);

        System.out.println(firstLetter + lastLetter);
    }
}
```